# Android Studio Libgdx More touches on screen

Tags: android, libgdx, touch

I have a problem when I need to press 2 buttons at the same time. I was using Gdx.input.getX() to take the coordinates and check which area is pressed, but when there are two touches at the same time, it doesn't work anymore. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use InputProcessor. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

For example:

```
public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    // pointer gives you the finger number which is pressed 0 = first, 1 = second....
    return false;
}
```